# "All phase plane solution points remain stationary as $t$ increases"?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear system $y′(t)=A\vec{y}(t)$,

where $A$ is a real $2\times2$ constant matrix with repeated eigenvalues.

All phase plane solution points remain stationary as $t$ increases.

I need to find the matrix $A$.

I'm a little confused here. I don't get how the solution points don't move. I've tried values that would make a center, but I guess that doesn't technically count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A=0$ makes every initial condition to be stationary.

The solution of the start edo is $y(t)=e^{At}y_0$, then for every point be stationary we need that $e^{At}=I$, this means that $At=0$, for every $t$, then the matrix $A=0$.

Comment: Oh! That worked but I thought the determinant couldn't be zero so I guess I ruled that one out. Just one of those instances where the answer is so trivial you don't think it could work.